# Facebook graph request error on Android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to make a dummy app to play around with Facebook's Android SDK. I currently have SSO and can stored the authentication token with the following code. Essentially it just signs on and then is supposed to make a call to get the userId and then another call when the test button is clicked to print it on the screen.

The authentication token prints fine, but I keep getting a Facebook error thrown when I try to make the call to the graph. What is odd, is that when I copy the request from the log and post it in a browser, I get a valid json response.

I know that it is not ideal to call directly from Facebook (an async request might be better for a polished app) but at the moment, I am just trying to get the basic api working.

Any suggestions?

```
//Standard Android imports
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner;
import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener;
import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;
import com.facebook.android.Util;
//Facebook Imports


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    //Something to test and increment to know things are changing
    private static int changeCounter;

    //Create a new Facebook object with the Facebook App ID (found on the facebook app online)
    public String APP_ID;
    Facebook facebook;
    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

    //For Facebook Async tasks
    private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        APP_ID = getString(R.string.APP_ID);
        facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
        mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);

        changeCounter = 0;

        //Add a button
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Perform action on click
                Log.v(TAG, "logout button clicked!");

                logoutOfFacebook();
            }
        });

        Button testButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        testButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.v(TAG, "testButton clicked");
                testViewPrint();
            }
        });

       checkFBAccessToken(); 
    }

    //Checks if there is an access token in the private mPrefs file and renews
    //the token if it is non existent or out of date
    private void checkFBAccessToken() {
        /* Get existing access_token if any */
        mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
        long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
        if (access_token != null) {
            facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
        }
        if (expires != 0) {
            facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
        }

        /* Only call authorize if the access_token has expired */
        if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
            renewFBAccessToken();
        }
    }

    //Renews the Facebook access Token and stores in the MODE_PRIVATE SharedPreferences
    private void renewFBAccessToken() {
        //Facebook permissions
        String[] permissions = { "user_location", "friends_location", "email" };

        facebook.authorize(this, permissions, new DialogListener() {
            //@Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                //Get the access token
                editor.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
                editor.putLong("access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires());

                editor.commit();

                //Test the user information recieved
                printUIDAndAuthToken();
            }

            //@Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

            public void onError(DialogError e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "There was an error logging out: " + e);
            }

            public void onCancel() {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCancel was hit");
            }

        });

    }

    //Prints the UID and AuthToken to the text view for testing purposes
    private void printUIDAndAuthToken() {
        TextView printOutView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        String authTokenStr = mPrefs.getString("access_token", "Did not get any AuthToken.");


        String uIdStr = mPrefs.getString("user_id", "Did not get any UID");
        printOutView.setText(changeCounter++ + uIdStr + " | \n" + authTokenStr);
    }

    private void getFBUserId() {
        //Also try to get and store the UID
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
        try {
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("acess_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
            editor.putLong("access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires());

            Log.v(TAG, facebook.getAccessToken() + " ||| =>");
            String jsonStringResponse = facebook.request("me", params);
            Log.v(TAG, jsonStringResponse);
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonStringResponse);
            String userId;
            userId = json.getString("id");
            editor.putString("user_id", userId);

        } catch (MalformedURLException m) {
            Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException");
            m.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException i) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException Caught");
            i.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Catch possible exception from request
            Log.e(TAG, "JSON or Facebook Error getting user ID: ");
            //Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        editor.commit();
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    //Prints out a bunch of testing info in the view
    private void testViewPrint() {
        //Testing
        getFBUserId();
        printUIDAndAuthToken();
    }

    //Code called by the button to logout of Facebook
    private void logoutOfFacebook() {

        mAsyncRunner.logout(this, new RequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {}

            @Override
            public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {}

            @Override
            public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e, Object state) {}

            @Override
            public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e, Object state) {}

            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {}
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer for any beginner Android developers that find themselves with the same error when working with the Facebook SDK.

It turns out that recent Android releases *require* you to make all network calls on a thread separate of the main thread (through AysncTask or your own Java threads). If you do try to make a network call on the main thread, instead of hanging the UI, it will simply throw an error as I experienced.